# Command echo still working as normal after removing

Tags: linux, redhat, echo

I want to remove `echo` command (which is located in `/bin/echo`), but the command echo still work as normal. When I use `which` command, it confirm that `echo` was removed

> /usr/bin/which: no echo in
>   (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

Do you know what's happening

Comment: Use `type echo` instead of `which echo` when debugging. While the reason here is the built-in, in a similar scenario command path cache might also interfere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash is also a builtin from your shell (e.g bash, ksh etc.)
so even if you remove the original echo binary, it will still work from your shell (but you will not have the arguments etc. available like with the binary)

see the bash builtins here : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

try to add this in the user .bash_profile (or from the shell) :

```
enable -p echo
```

and try to run echo again
(ref : https://astoryworthtelling.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/disable-bash-builtin-commands/) and it shouldn't work

Comment: `-p` prints the state. You wanted to suggest `-n`.

Comment: I did not fix, I do not edit others' code on SO. Please do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Echo is a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) builtin command, which is what you're seeing.

I guess the real question is: why do you want to do this? There are many, many programs that rely on echo, all of which will break if you disable this command.

Comment: I have a program, which using echo command to interact with system, and I want to test for all the case

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a great demonstration of why it's a bad idea to use echo in scripts that you want to be portable. It's often overridden by shell built ins.

Have a look at

```
man bash
```

And search for echo to find where the built in version is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, you can still override echo with an alias

```
alias echo=':'
```